# windows 7 crashes while attaching an embedded image using phpmailer

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, phpmailer, wampserver

I am writing a script to send birthday messages automatically to employees. For now I have taken hard-coded email ids. Now the problem is that these scripts are working perfectly well on my laptop Windows 10 Wampserver3.0.6. But now when I am transfering these files to the main desktop in the office(Windows 7 Wampserver3.1.3), the email sending based scripts crash the computer when you embed or attach an image. If I remove the attachment and send only the text, the email gets sent. But on attaching an image the computer crashes directly. The code is as follows:

```
require("PHPMailer-master\src\PHPMailer.php");
require("PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php");
require("PHPMailer-master\src\Exception.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();                
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;               
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;             
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';          
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;                                      
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "********";
$mail->SetFrom("abc@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Happy birthday!";
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('compressed.jpg', 'compressed');
$mail->Body = "<h1>Happy Birthday!</h1><br>Have a wonderful day!";
$mail->AddAddress("abc@gmail.com","def@hotmail.com");
 if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```

I have tried so many things. I have increased the `memory_limit` of wamp server.
An additional thing, debug=1 displays the process on chrome. So if i embed an image, it stops halfway, it does not display the process completely and crashes in the middle.
**NOTE: addAttachment() works well but addEmbeddedImage() crashes the computer**
It works perfectly well on my laptop. Please help.

Comment: try installing the same version of wamp on the machine that crashes.

Comment: Define "crashes"; enable error display so you can see what the problem is. Also, there's no point in using an embedded image if you're not going to refer to it in your HTML Body source.

Comment: I do use the embedded images in my code. I just posted one of the version of my code where those 2 lines are not written. But either way it crashes

Comment: @Synchro I try to put it within try catch but I am unable to catch the errors

Comment: Enable error display in PHP.ini, check your web server error log.

Comment: And you still have not told us what you mean by crashing, so it’s difficult to help you.